# Customized right click Menu in a Web Page text area!

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing an application in C# using visual web developer. I'm displaying some text for reading and I want the user to be able to select a word or fragment, and then right click it to display a customized menu (One that has for example define, search, show grammar...). I
I don't know how to do it. I'm fairly new to the .Net

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that entirely on the client-side, in JavaScript.

Note that it's considered a bad idea to take over right-click, which the user has the right to expect will work the same no matter which application they are using.

Comment: True. However I disagree in textareas. It's quite common use, even in the browser, to select some text and rightclick to do something with it (or selecting a link and rightclick to 'unlink' it).

Comment: @Jan: I'm not sure I agree with "quite common". If you added something to my menu, that would be fine. But taking over the menu is another story.

Comment: Google Maps takes over right-click (on compatible browsers) and it is useful. Overall it's probably a good thing that Opera does not allow anything to change the context-menu, but it would be nice to have the option of allowing sites to add to it, especially for something like Google Maps.

Comment: Sounds good. Though I'm not sure how to use that. Besides, would I be able to manipulate my data easily if I have to use Javascript? I need for example to query a database for definitions for a selected word. I guess a menu in c# is better. no?

Comment: @Wael: the only way to get a right-click menu is client side, in JavaScript. There is no such thing on the server side.